# Ocaml: How to define function with specific type

Tags: ocaml

I know this could be stupid question, but since I'm new to Ocaml, please give me some tips on defining functions with specific type.

I want to define function which type has int * int * (int -> int) -> int

So I made a function like this.

```
let rec sigma a b func:int->int= 
    if a >= b then func(a)
    else func(a) + sigma(a+1, b, func)
```

But sigma function here does not have type `int * int * (int->int) -> int`. Instead its type is int->int->(int->int)->int.

How should I define function sigma to have type `int * int * (int->int) -> int`?

(Error Message :

```
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b * 'c
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `int * int * (int->int) -> int` denotes a function that takes a 3-tuple and returns and integer. A tuple (pair, triple, quadruple, etc) is written as `(a,b,c,...)`, e.g.,

```
 let rec sigma (a,b,func) : int = 
    if a >= b then func(a)
    else func(a) + sigma(a+1, b, func)
```

With all that said, it is usually a bad idea to pass arguments via tuples in OCaml. It hampers currying, inefficient (each tuple is boxed into a separate value), and in general non-functional and not nice.

Also, when you constrain a parameter of a function, you shall parenthesize it, e.g., `(func : int -> int)`.

And normally functions in OCaml are applied by juxtaposition of a function name and its arguments, e.g., given a function `add`

```
let add x y = x + y
```

we can apply (call it) just as `add 3 5` (not `add(3,5)`!)

Therefore, the conventional way to define your sigma function would be

```
let rec sigma a b func : int = 
  if a >= b then func a
  else func a + sigma (a+1) b func
```